# Trace flag 10260 on SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2016, trace-flags

Our SQL Server 2016 development servers have trace flag 10260 set on start up.
The other servers that run SQL Server 2016 do not.
I've searched high and low, but have not been able to find any info on the subject.

What does this trace flag do?

Is it safe to remove?

Comment: I don't see anything about 10260, but closest one I've found (10204) is about disabling merge/recompress during columnstore index reorganization. So I'm guessing 10260 might about something related to columnstore indexes.
  Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396.aspx

Comment: Any monitoring tool used to monitor the server which has the trace flag enabled and what application connects to this database ?

Comment: @Shanky; no monitoring tools installed. But could it be related to RC3 being installed first, and then upgraded to RTM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At some point in the pre-RTM phase, it was used for some Polybase related process. As far as I can tell, it's 10260 is no longer in use for RTM so you can remove. Doesn't actually do anything anymore.

Comment: @Joe, As it is coming from a reliable source, I'll take your word for it. Thank you very much.